# Problem with release upgrade 9.04 to 9.10

Tags: upgrade, 9.10, 9.04

I recently tried upgrade from 9.04 to 9.10 on my netbook, but something went wrong, and X session hang up. After reboot I still can log to system, but Gnome is rather broken.

I found that I can issue command "sudo do-release-upgrade" to continue upgrade, but it tries to do upgrade from 9.10 to 10.04, even I have "jaunty" in /etc/apt/sources.list.

I guess thats because some information in system has 9.10 in version, like "lsb_release -a" gives "Release: 9.10"

My question is:
Where I should change release information, so "sudo do-release-upgrade" can do upgrade 9.04 -> 9.10, not 9.10 -> 10.4

---

I know how to copy /home dir and reinstall system with preservation of this dir, I'm just curios if there is way to rescue sys by working with apt-get, aptitude, and dpkg. I'm sure that all changes were made only by these tools so maybe there is way to fix it. And, yes I know that 9.10 is a little bit outdated but it is still supported and I use it because of software compatibility.

Comment: Trying to fix your 9.10 installation is folly. You need to backup your data and take note of your installed apps, then do a clean install of 10.10. Fixing a broken install is difficult, and even if you succeed, you'll have an installation two release cycles behind. It's simply not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably better to run `sudo apt-get -f install` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` instead.  That should install/upgrade all the packages that were marked by the upgrade process but didn't get installed yet because of the crash.

Comment: "sudo apt-get -f install" gives me output that says: "/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d:274 /sbin/runlevel: not found"

Comment: After trying to install initscripts I have: "dpkg: cannot find "update-rc.d" in path".

Comment: "/sbin/runlevel not found" means the `upstart` package isn't installed completely/correctly—that's really bad.

Comment: Did you also try the dpkg command I gave?

Comment: Yes, I tried also dpkg command.

Answer (score 0):

This command helped me, when a power cut interrupted my install. But I was upgrading from Lucid to Maverick.

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Just as an anecdote, I once copied the contents of /var/cache/apt from 8.10 into 9.10, so I could roll-back to 9.04. Suffice to say, I had to do a clean install later.